# how to store arraylist value in string array

Tags: casting, arraylist, itext, arrays

> **com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: java.lang.ArrayStoreException**

Q. When trying following code which is trying to change ArrayList to String[] array type above Exception happened.I don't know what's wrong.

```
try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/falg_check";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "root");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs4 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from records");
        String[] arrayOfStrings;          
        ArrayList<String[]> name=new ArrayList<String[]>(); 
        while(rs4.next()){
            String insert =rs4.getString("name");
            final String[] res={insert};                
            name.add(res);                                                  
        }
        //Object[] x=name.toArray();


 arrayOfStrings = name.toArray(new String[name.size()]); //<---------------
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
            throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
        }
```

**`EDIT:`** **I have a requirement of one dimensional array so that I can put those values in  text.setChoices(arrayOfStrings); which sets choices in dropdown menu in PDF file through JAVA.**

> **EDIT: HOW IT IS NOT DUPLICATE.:**

I wanted the ArrayList to change the type in reference with String Array which isn't the case with any question on stackoverflow. And that too I wanted single dimensional array. It isn't too difficult to understand the difference between 2D int Array and linear String Array.Yes may be the concept matches with several other type casting problems but it's partially/conditionally different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined

```
ArrayList<String[]> name=new ArrayList<String[]>()
```

When you call `name.toArray()`, you get an array of elements of the type the original list contains. As your list contains `String[]` instances, `name.toArray()` returns a `String[][]`, i.e. an array of String *arrays*, not an array of Strings.

Thus, either you actually have to work with that array of string arrays:

```
String[][] arrayOfStrings;
...
arrayOfStrings = name.toArray(new String[name.size()][]);
```

Or you work with a list of Strings instead of a list of String arrays:

```
ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs4.next())
{
    String insert = rs4.getString("name");
    name.add(insert);
}
```

Or you flatten the list of String arrays to a list of Strings before converting to an array:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings;
ArrayList<String[]> name = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while(rs4.next())
{
    String insert = rs4.getString("name");
    final String[] res={insert};
    name.add(res);
}
....
ArrayList<String> intermediate = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String[] stringArray: name)
{
    if (stringArray != null)
    {
        intermediate.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(stringArray));
    }
}
arrayOfStrings = intermediate.toArray(new String[name.size()]);
```

Comment: That's what I needed..Bulls-eye